# getting values from array that got indexes in second array

Tags: php, arrays

From the array named `$words` I would like to get only those words that got indexes from array `$indexes`. All I got:

```
public function createNewWordsList($indexes)
{
    $words = $this->wordsArray();
    $licznik = 0;
    $result = array();

    foreach($words AS $i => $word)
    {
        if($i == $indexes[$licznik])
        {
            $licznik++;
            $result[] = $word;
        }
    }
    print_r($word);
}
```

but it don't work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you iterate over the wrong array. If `indexes` contains the keys you want to keep from `$words` (together with their associated values) then the code should be like:

```
public function createNewWordsList(array $indexes)
{
    $words  = $this->wordsArray();
    $result = array();

    // Iterate over the list of keys (indexes) to copy into $result
    foreach ($indexes as $key) {
        // Copy the (key, value) into $result only if the key exists in $words
        if (array_key_exists($key, $words)) {
            $result[$key] = $words[$key];
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

If you don't need the original keys (indexes) into the returned array you can change the code above by either add the values into `$result` using `$result[] = $words[$key];` or discard the keys before returning `$result` using `return array_values($result);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function createNewWordsList($indexes)
{
    $words = $this->wordsArray();
    $licznik = 0;
    $result = array();

    foreach($words AS $i => $word)
    {
        if(in_array($word,$indexes)) //check using in_array
        {
            $licznik++;
            $result[] = $word;
        }
    }
    print_r($word);
}
```

Comment: This checks values from arrays not indexes like OP is requesting.